# Parse.com - Logging Caught Exceptions

Tags: android, parse-platform

Can we send caught errors to Parse.com bugs dashboard like this example from Crashlytics

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here! 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Parse Crash Reporting](http://blog.parse.com/learn/introducing-parse-crash-reporting-2/)?